# Finding The Highest Integer and Corresponding String From Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is more of a continuation of the same python program I was using in my previous question. I have 14 lists. 10 lists contain the make and model of a car, followed by the value of each car, followed by the quantity of cars of each make/model. 3 lists contain the appended values from the first ten; one contains strictly the make/model, the next contains strictly the integer value of each car, and the last contains strictly the quantity of each make/model. The 14th list contains the first 10 lists as one main list.

I'm trying to find the highest integer value of a car, then find the corresponding string name of that car, and print both to the screen. I have the highest integer value, and have it formatted to print as currency, but I do not know how to find the name of the car that corresponds to that integer value.

I'll add examples for context.

My current code:

```
def getList(all):
    x = 0
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        list0.append(all[x][0])
        list1.append(all[x][1])
        list2.append(all[x][2])
    print()
    print("Vehicle Inventory by Type")
    print("Inventory       Make/Model")
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        print("%9d       %-1s" % (list2[x], list0[x]))
    return all, list0, list1, list2


def getHighest(all, list0, list1):
    print("Highest MRSP:")
    i = max(list1)
    if i == (all[9][1]):
        print("yes")
    print('${:,.2f}'.format(i))


list0 = []
list1 = []
list2 = []

car1 = ["Chevy Bolt EV", 37495, 2]
car2 = ["Kia Niro", 24485, 23]
car3 = ["VW e-Golf", 32790, 12]
car4 = ["Hyundai Kona", 37495, 3]
car5 = ["Honda Insight", 23725, 4]
car6 = ["Chevrolet Volt", 34395, 14]
car7 = ["Hyundai Ioniq", 23285, 5]
car8 = ["Tesla Model 3", 45200, 1]
car9 = ["Audi e-tron", 75795, 2]
car10 = ["Toyota Prius", 24405, 12]

all = (car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8, car9, car10)

getList(all)
print()
getHighest(all, list0, list1)
```

The "if" statement in the function "getHighest" is my attempt to try and figure out the logic for this, but I know I have it wrong, and I don't know how to get what I am looking for.

Forgot to add the result from the function "getList":

```
Vehicle Inventory by Type
Inventory       Make/Model
        2       Chevy Bolt EV
       23       Kia Niro
       12       VW e-Golf
        3       Hyundai Kona
        4       Honda Insight
       14       Chevrolet Volt
        5       Hyundai Ioniq
        1       Tesla Model 3
        2       Audi e-tron
       12       Toyota Prius
```

As an example, the Audi e-tron would have the highest value in this specific series of lists, with an integer value of 75795, so I would like to grab both the value and the name and display both to the screen.

What I am looking for as an example:

```
Highest MSRP:
Audi e-tron at $75,795.00
```

What I have currently as an example:

```
Highest MSRP:
$75,795.00
```

I have attempted to research this type of problem on Google, but I can't seem to find anything relevant. Whether that is from my not explaining it correctly in my search, or my not looking in the right places, I don't know. Regardless, any help would be greatly appreciated, as I don't know what I should be doing.

Comment: In your function `def getHighest()`, you never use the `list0`

Comment: I know. I passed it into the function thinking I would need to use it, then I got stuck with the logic, so I never continued with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `max` here, use the second element `MRSP` `x[1]` to evaluate:

```
all_cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8, car9, car10]
max_car = max(all_cars , key=lambda x:x[1])
print('{} at ${:,.2f}'.format(*max_car))
```

output:

```
Audi e-tron at $75,795.00
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. I used this code to get exactly what I wanted:

`max_car = max(all, key=lambda x: x[1])`

`print(max_car[0], "with an MSRP of", '${:,.2f}'.format(max_car[1]))`

Thank you.

Comment: @Dev-MDW2 That's nice - however, do not use python keywords like e.g. `all` as variable names, as it will create problems if you want to use the according functionality. `all_cars` is the better choice here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Python library called `pandas`, which will make your task much more easier.

Can you try the following:

```
car1 = ["Chevy Bolt EV", 37495, 2]
car2 = ["Kia Niro", 24485, 23]
car3 = ["VW e-Golf", 32790, 12]
car4 = ["Hyundai Kona", 37495, 3]
car5 = ["Honda Insight", 23725, 4]
car6 = ["Chevrolet Volt", 34395, 14]
car7 = ["Hyundai Ioniq", 23285, 5]
car8 = ["Tesla Model 3", 45200, 1]
car9 = ["Audi e-tron", 75795, 2]
car10 = ["Toyota Prius", 24405, 12]

all_cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8, car9, car10]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_cars, columns=['car_name', 'price', 'qty'])
print(df.sort_values(by=['price'], ascending=[False]))
```

If you want to get the first values, you can do the following:

```
result = df.sort_values(by=['price'], ascending=[False]).iloc[0]
print(result['car_name'])
print("{:,}".format(result['price']))
```

Comment: I'm trying it now.

Comment: Is the pandas library included by default with Python? I'm getting a traceback error concerning it.

Comment: I downloaded the pandas library. While this worked with the library installed, I can't be sure if anyone else who will eventually use this will have that library. Unless it is included by default and I just don't have it for whatever reason. 

In which case, I don't know how that would have happened. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function `def getHighest()` with this one:

```
def getHighest(all, list0, list1):
    print("Highest MRSP:")
    i = max(list1)
    c = [j for j, lst in enumerate(all) if i in lst][0]
    car = all[c][0]
    if i == (all[9][1]):
        print("yes")
    print('{} at ${:,.2f}'.format(car,i))
```